# Having a problem in database selection mysql

Tags: mysql

I have this table `table chats` and `tbl_suggested`. On table chats i have

```
  id       questions         answer            date
  1        What is life                        2020-02-08   
  2        what is PC      personal computer   2020-02-08
  3        What is life uk   good              2020-02-08
  4        where is the cr   there             2020-02-08
```

On the `tbl_suggest` i have this

```
      id       chats_id      questions                      
      1            1          What is life in spain         
      2            1         what is liefe in uk               
      3            1          What is life  in paris
```

I query this code

```
SELECT chats.id,chats.question,chats.answer,tbl_suggest.questions,chats.date 
from chats LEFT JOIN tbl_suggest on chats.id= tbl_suggest.chats_id O
RDER by chats.date ASC
```

> result is, then i want to remove that two what is life question on the second and third row

```
chat.id chat.questions    chat.answer     tbl_suggest.question     chats.date
  1      what is life                     what is life in spain       2020-02-08
  1      what is life                     what is liefe in uk         2020-02-08
  1      what is life                     what is life in paris       2020-02-08
  2      what is PC       personal computer                           2020-02-08       
  3       What is life uk  good                                        2020-02-08
  4      where is the cr   there                                      2020-02-08
```

I want is to remove the what is life redudant like this

```
   chat.questions        chat.answer     tbl_suggest.question       chats.date
   what is life                          what is life in spain       2020-02-08
                                          what is liefe in uk         2020-02-08
                                         what is life in paris       2020-02-08
   what is PC          personal computer                             2020-02-08       
   What is life uk      good                                         2020-02-08
   where is the cr       there                                      2020-02-08
```

to show it properly in my dialog box

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in application code

Comment: But sir if it possible to remove the same chat id and set it to null without removing some row?

Comment: Possible? Of course. Sensible? Not really, unless no presentation layer is available

Comment: i dont know how to remove it btw. limiting to one the id and the remaining same id is converting to null