# Having a trouble in mysql select statement

Tags: mysql

[Having a problem in database selection mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60128664/having-a-problem-in-database-selection-mysql)

- I want to update my question
- I have had a problem in the database query
- I will make it simple

Query:

```
SELECT chats.id,chats.question,chats.answer,tbl_suggest.questions as suggestions,
chats.date from chats left JOIN tbl_suggest on chats.id= tbl_suggest.questions_id
ORDER by chats.date ASC
```

For example, I have a result set like this

```
id question                     answer             suggestions           date   
1   what is it it it?                                What is it?        2020-02-08 21:06:14
1   what is it it it?                                what is it dept?   2020-02-08 21:06:14
2   what is It?              Information Technology.    NULL            2020-02-08 21:09:33
3                               No Answer               NULL            2020-02-08 21:09:36
4   what is it it it it it?                           What is it?       2020-02-08 21:10:26
4   what is it it it it it?                           what is it dept?  2020-02-08 21:10:26
```

All I want is to remove the redundant in column question and id but not removing the row to able to see the list of suggestions like this

```
questions               answer   suggestion
what is it it it it?             what is it
                                 what is it dept?
```

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you are trying to get only the output requested.

```
SELECT chats.id,chats.question,chats.answer,tbl_suggest.questions as suggestions,chats.date from chats left 
JOIN tbl_suggest on chats.id= tbl_suggest.questions_id 
WHERE question = "what is it it it it?"
ORDER by chats.date ASC
```

Otherwise, you can just use a GROUP BY

```
SELECT chats.id,chats.question,chats.answer,tbl_suggest.questions as suggestions,chats.date from chats left 
JOIN tbl_suggest on chats.id= tbl_suggest.questions_id 
GROUP BY question ORDER by chats.date ASC
```

Comment: if i use your suggestions the column(suggestion) will limit into 1 the user of my chat bot will not able to see other suggestions only 1

Comment: hmmm. i think my idea is not possible sorry dude. Im asking for bulk data where is not enough

Comment: I'm toying around with using LIKE and wildcards "%" to achieve what you are looking for. It's an interesting concept.

Comment: Try this: SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE question LIKE replace(suggestions," ", "%")

Comment: i already solve my problem haha. i use dual select. Thanks for your effort. :)